# Open Accordion Item Based on #target in URL - Wordpress Menu

Tags: jquery, wordpress, anchor, accordion

I have an accordion that has three content areas. I want to activate the relative accordion when someone clicks on a menu item that has an anchor appended to the url (/expertise#target). The way my accordion is set up, it adds `.show` to the panel `.panel` that is clicked on the title element `.panelTrigger`. I am trying to figure out how to connect the triggering based on the #target on the end of the url. Another issue, is that wordpress is adding a / before the hash.

**HTML**

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
<?php if (have_rows('accordion')) {
$count = 0;
while (have_rows('accordion'))  { the_row(); $count++; ?>
        <div class="parentPanel item-<?php echo $count; ?>">
             <a class="panelTrigger" href="#<?php the_sub_field('accordion_title'); ?>"><?php the_sub_field('accordion_title'); ?></a>

                <div class="panel" id="<?php the_sub_field('accordion_title'); ?>">
                    <div class="greenLine"></div>
                    <?php the_sub_field('accordion_content'); ?>

                    <?php if (have_rows('accordion_logos')) {
                        echo ' <h3>CREDENTIALS</h3><div class="logos">';
                        while (have_rows('accordion_logos')) { the_row(); ?>

                            <img src="<?php the_sub_field('logo'); ?>"/>
                  <?php }
                    echo '</div>';
                    } ?>

        </div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.accordion > .parentPanel:last-of-type > .panel').css('display','block');


$('.panelTrigger').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let $this = $(this);

    if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
        $this.next().removeClass('show');
        $this.next().slideUp(350);
    } else {
        $this.parent().parent().find('.panel').removeClass('show');
        $this.parent().parent().find('.panel').slideUp(350);
        $this.next().toggleClass('show');
        $this.next().slideToggle(350);
    }
});

$('.panelTrigger').bind('click',function(){
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function() {
        theOffset = $(self).offset();
        $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: theOffset.top - 180 });
    }, 310); // ensure the collapse animation is done
});
```

I know this is possible, just have to figure out how to connect the trigger or add `.show` to the #target panel. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get value after *hash* when your page loads and then using this value simply add `show` class to panel and toggle same.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //let url = window.location.hash.substr(1)
  //var to_open = "#" + url;
  //this is just for demo...
  let url = "www.someth.com/somehtins#xyz";
  var to_open = "#" + url.split('#')[1];
  $(to_open).prev().addClass('active')
  $(to_open).addClass("show") //add class where id matches
  $(to_open).slideToggle(350); //show that
})
```

```css
.panel {
  display: none
}

.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion" id="accordion">
  <div class="parentPanel item-1">
    <a class="panelTrigger" href="#abc">
    Soemthing..
    </a>

    <div class="panel" id="abc">
      <div class="greenLine"></div>
      <img src="<?php the_sub_field('logo'); ?>" />
    </div>

    <div class="parentPanel item-2">
      <a class="panelTrigger" href="#xyz">
       Soemthings xyz
      </a>

      <div class="panel" id="xyz">
        <div class="greenLine"></div>
        xyzz
        <img src="<?php the_sub_field('logo'); ?>" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. It seems that auto `/` is getting in the way, because if it would just leave the hash and target, then I think it would work?

Comment: how is your current url look alike ? can you show that

Comment: the url is `/expertise#Independent` in the MENU...but when it redirects to the page it changes to /expertise/#Independent.

Comment: it should still work because here `hash.substr(1) ` and even `split('#')[1]` getting value after `#` . Please can you check if html which i am using is correct and it matches your html structure ? Also , do `console.log(window.location.hash.substr(1) )` see what its giving you .

Comment: HTML looks fine except Im not using bootstrap

Comment: what does `console.log(window.location.hash.substr(1) )` gives you ?

Comment: `console.log` isn't giving me anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228216/discussion-between-swati-and-edgaralexpoe).